# Passing Pointer to Rust Array into x86-64 Asm -- Pointer Off by One

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, ffi

When I pass pointers to arrays from Rust into x86-64 Asm, the relevant registers (rdi, rsi) appear to be off by one, pointing to element 1 of the array instead of element 0.  I can decrement the registers to access the desired location, but I am concerned about the unexpected behavior.  Are there possible explanations for this that I am overlooking?

The most relevant portions of a simple program to illustrate this follows.

**main.rs**

```
extern crate utilities;

fn main() {
    let input: [u8;8] = [0;8];
    let output: [u64; 1] = [0;1];

    let input_ptr = input.as_ptr();
    let output_ptr = output.as_ptr();

    utilities::u8tou64(input_ptr,output_ptr);

    for i in 0..8 {print!("{:02X}", input[i]);} // byte 1 will be 0xEE
    println!();
    println!("{:016X}", output[0].swap_bytes());  /* byte 1 position of the u64
    will be 0xFF */

    println!("{:02X}",  unsafe{*input_ptr.offset(1)}); /* modifying byte at address
    passed into rdi in Asm function modifies input_ptr.offset(1) when expected
    behavior was modification of input_ptr with no offset, e.g. input[0] */
}
```

**u8_to_u64.S**

```
.globl u8_to_u64
.intel_syntax noprefix
u8_to_u64:
    mov rax, 0xff
    mov byte [rsi], rax
    mov rax, 0xee
    mov byte [rdi], rax
    xor rax, rax
retq
```

Comment: Why are you using 7-byte `mov r64, sign_extended_imm32` for 1-byte constants?  `mov byte ptr [rsi], 0xff` / `mov byte ptr [rdi], 0xee` / `xor eax,eax` is way shorter and more efficient.  As a bonus, it will actually assemble, unlike `mov byte [rdi], rax` which has a mismatch between byte and qword operand size.  (`al` is the low byte of RAX).  Also, GAS's `.intel_syntax` is MASM-like, so you need `byte ptr`, not NASM-style `byte`.  Unless Rust uses a different assembler that only sort of looks like GAS, this isn't your real asm code.

Comment: @PeterCordes the program I posted was simplified from what I was trying to do. My real program uses Asm to convert a 136 byte array pointed to by RDI into a 17 element u64 array in RSI.  What I posted does run as I built the simplified program and copied directly from it. I switched from passing in a pointer, instead passing in a borrowed reference to the array, and at least in this case, that caused the off by one error to go away. Seems like an FFI bug.  I'll try your suggestions in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assembled your asm with `gcc -c foo.S`, since I thought I'd get an assemble-time error from `byte` instead of `byte ptr`, and the mismatch with a qword register.

In GAS syntax, **`byte` evaluates to the integer constant `1`**, so `mov byte [rsi], rax` is equivalent to `mov 1[rsi], rax`.  This is valid in GAS syntax, and is equivalent to `[1+rsi]`

When you disassemble `foo.o` with `objdump -dwrC -Mintel`, you see

```
0000000000000000 <u8_to_u64>:
   0:   48 c7 c0 ff 00 00 00    mov    rax,0xff
   7:   48 89 46 01             mov    QWORD PTR [rsi+0x1],rax
   b:   48 c7 c0 ee 00 00 00    mov    rax,0xee
  12:   48 89 47 01             mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x1],rax
  16:   48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  19:   c3                      ret
```

Notice the `[rsi+1]` and `[rdi+1]` addressing modes.

GAS syntax for what you're trying to do is:

```
mov   byte ptr [rsi], 0xff
mov   byte ptr [rdi], 0xee
xor   eax,eax
ret
```

Or with stupid extra instructions to do a mov-immediate to a register first:

```
mov   eax, 0xff
mov   [rsi], al
mov   eax, 0xee     # mov al, 0xee  is shorter but false dependency on the old RAX
mov   [rdi], al
xor   eax,eax
ret
```

Comment: This corrected the issue.  I had tried moving immediates into [rdi] and [rsi] and gotten a complaint from the compiler about it.  Using "mov byte ptr" instead of "mov byte" allowed the direct immediates assignment and eliminated the "off by one" error I was inadvertently introducing into the program.

Comment: @WDS: without an operand-size specifier, `mov [mem], imm` is ambiguous and gives an error, yes.  That was your first hint that your syntax wasn't doing what you wanted.  The fact that `mov byte [rsi], rax` (with a qword register) *didn't* give an error even though you were trying to specify byte operand size was your other clue that your code didn't mean (to GAS) what you intended.